# Developing asp.net mvc on linux

Tags: linux, fedora, asp.net

I am trying to get rid of Windows, and switch to Fedora. In college I'm learning a lot of asp.net MVC 5.

Now. I know I can do asp.net Core on Linux, with vs code and so on, but is it possible for me to use something like Rider, to develop web apps using MVC 5? I tried using Rider, but it yelled at me for not having msbuild.

I looked into mono, but after some research I don't know if it's good. The problem is my projects need to be compatible with my professor's Visual Studio on Windows. Is there a semi normal way to make it work?

I'm using Fedora.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From student to student, I'd say that the easiest way to work your semester would be to create a Windows VM, have all your code in some version control system like git, program on whatever you want to, and before presenting your project to your professor, try it on your VM.

The main reason is that since you are using Microsoft's products, and you are a student, all the configuration, and work that you could invest trying to generate a semi-decent workspace could be invested into researching other things. At the end of the semester, you can just delete your VM and then take all your code from git and use it whenever you need to.

Comment: So just use Windows? I still have it installed, but I'm starting to really enjoy Linux and wanted to just do more on it.

Comment: well... as sad as it could be... yes :( ... I struggled many months and is always harder to emulate something 100% Microsoft in Linux... on the other hand, if you invest all the time that you wanted to invest creating a semi-windows system, you could learn some other cool stuff like bash-scripting, source-compiling, kernel tunning, there are myriads of things to learn in linux :)

Answer (score 0):

JetBrains does provide a free evaluation period, so if I were you, I'd install it on Fedora and verify that the current level of compatibility with MSVS is sufficient for your needs.
Of course you could also run Windows in VM, install MS's VS Community edition and use that as a back-up option, assuming that your instructor won't require the use of features only available in Professional or Enterprise editions.

Comment: I have VS Enterprise. For free with school. I tried JetBrains' Raider for .NET, this is the one yelling about msbuild. Removing an actual Windows and installing it with virtual machine kind of makes no sense for me in this case. I also have all JetBrains products for free (student)